# pycaffe Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type

Tags: python, c++, caffe, convolution, pycaffe

I implemented DeformableConvolution which is a new type of convolution layer in caffe. It is inherited from BaseConvolution class just like ConvolutionLayer and has the same parameter as convolution.

Now I can use `./build/tools/caffe XXX` to train and test net contains this new layer as expected. But when I use pycaffe to visualize features. It came to this error.

pycaffe command:

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
net = caffe.Net(‘mnist/mnist.prototxt',
            ‘models/mnist_iter_5000.caffemodel',
            caffe.TEST)
```

error:

```
layer_factory.hpp:81] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) 
                      Unknown layer type: DeformableConvolution
```

I searched it and found it was mainly caused by missing codes in `caffe.proto` and `layer_factory.cpp`. Since this layer has same parameters as normal convolution layer, I have no idea how should I deal with this two files. And it can be trained as expected by `./build/tools/caffe`, so I wonder if this is caused only by something related to pycaffe?

layer demo:

```
layer {
  name: "conv11"
  type: "DeformableConvolution"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "conv11_offset"
  top: "conv11"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    dilation: 1
    pad: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: have you `make pycaffe` after adding the new layer?

Comment: @Shai, yes. I also tried `make clean & make all & make pycaffe`

Comment: Are you sure your `PYTHONPATH` points to the right caffe version? is it possible you have several caffe versions on your machine and python loads the wrong one?

Comment: @Shai yes, I just checked again.

Comment: Do you see `'DeformabelConvolution'` in the list output from `list(caffe.layer_type_list())`?

Comment: @Shai em...it's there and it suddenly loaded the net as expected. I don't know what I have done to make it back normal. It's so weird... Thank you very very much !!

Comment: You should check for the [negation field](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=821).

Comment: according to this link,it seems you might not have built caffe with 
 WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1 in Makefile.config not set to one,kindly confirm https://github.com/faustomilletari/VNet/issues/31

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Actually, I did. Thank you still.